# 'Assert True' concept in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I am using `selenium` to compare names present inside a `web-table`, I have declared local variables which has first name and second name and am comparing that with values present in a web-table.

For a positive flow my code runs properly and it shows the expected result.

For a negative flow where the name in the declared string `lastname` doesn't match with the value present in the web-table, the expected result is not shown. The message present in `assertTrue` is not getting printed. My eclipse shows `testng` is running but nothing happens after that.

My assumption if the `web-table` has any last name other than 'Product' then record found should get the value false and it should move to 'AssertTrue' line and should print the stmt `Lastname is not as expected`.

```
@Test 
public void abc(){
    String firstname="Test";
    String lastname="Product";

    boolean recordfound= false;

    String firstpart="//*[@id='fchArea']/table/tbody/tr[";
    String secondpart="]/td[1]/a";
    int i=8;
    while (iselementpresent(firstpart+i+secondpart)){
        //firstname
        String name1=driver.findElement(By.xpath(firstpart+i+secondpart)).getText();

        if (name1.equals(firstname)){
            String altofsecondpart = firstpart+i+secondpart.replace("td[1]", "td[2]");
            String name2=driver.findElement(By.xpath(altofsecondpart)).getText();

            if(name2.equals(lastname)){
                System.out.println("secondcase pass");
                recordfound = true;
                break;
            }
        }   
    }
    Assert.assertTrue(recordfound, "Lastname is not as expected");
}

public boolean iselementpresent(String xpath){  
    int lst=driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpath)).size();
    if(lst == 0){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML in the question and format it so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop goes on infinite and always it check element for index 8, as you have fixed i value. so you should increment or decrements i value. But in that case if row number not exist then it give element not found error.

So best way to capture number of rows in web table then iterate loop for the same.

Thanks,
-Sadik

Comment: Hi, I have used a break statement in the second 'if' condition to avoid continuous looping.

Comment: Logically this will break when your both condition true.